# How do I view which versions of Elasticsearch plugin I am using

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch

How do I view the versions of the elasticsearch plugins I am using? I have tried

```
$ES_HOME/bin/plugin --list
```

but it doesn't give the version

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Nodes Info api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-info.html) to query the plugin list and version

Example:

> curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/_all/plugins

Comment: This showed all the plugins. But for all the plugins that I had installed, it just showed "NA". I guess the plugins need to be developed in a standard format for ES to understand and display that info.

Comment: If they are site plugins, I don't think developpers add that info in es-plugin.properties file.

Comment: For JVM plugins, well, it depends. For "official" plugins, you should see a version. What plugin does not give you a version?